Conditional joint probability question
I am working on a proof for my Economics thesis and I wanted to confirm one step.
I have the following expression:
$$\frac{p(A \& B | C)}{p(A \& B)}.$$
Is it true that this is the same as the following?
$$\frac{p(A|C)p(B|A,C)}{p(A)p(B|C)} $$
I am pretty sure it is correct but I couldn't find the formulas in my go-to textbooks. Any confirmation and link to a textbook treatment would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Well, let's work an example.  Say you are tossing a fair die and let $$A=\{1,2,4\}\quad B=\{2,3\}\quad C=\{2,3,6\}$$
We compute the first expression:
$A\cap B=\{2\}$ so the numerator is $\frac 13$.  The denominator is $\frac 16$ so the first term is $2$.
What about the second expression?  $P(A\,|\,C)=\frac 13$, $A\cap C=\{2\}$ so $P(B\,|\,A\cap C)=1$  Thus the numerator is $\frac 13$.  The denominator is $\frac 13\times \frac 23=\frac 13$ so the second term is $1$.
Thus the expressions are not equal.
In general, the first term resolves to $$\frac {P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(A\cap B)P(C)}$$  while the second expression resolves to $$\frac {P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)P(A)}$$
(Sanity Check:  using my example we have $A\cap B\cap C=\{2\}$ so the numerators are both $\frac 16$ but $P(A\cap B)=\frac 16$ and $P(C)=\frac 12$ so the first term is $2$ as before.  While the denominator of the second term is $\frac 13\times \frac 12=\frac 16$ making the second expression $1$ as before.)

No, this is not generally true.
$$\frac{p(AB|C)}{p(AB)}=\frac{p(A|C)p(B|AC)}{p(A)p(B|C)}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow p(AB|C)p(A)p(B|C)=p(AB)p(A|C)p(B|AC)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{p(ABC)p(A)p(BC)}{[p(C)]^2}=\frac{p(AB)p(AC)p(ABC)}{p(C)p(AC)}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{p(A)p(BC)}{p(C)}=p(AB)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow p(A)p(BC)=p(AB)p(C)$$
while $ p(A)p(BC)=p(AB)p(C)$ is not generally true.
Therefore unless you are assuming $ p(A)p(BC)=p(AB)p(C)$ in practice (for example, A, B, and C are independent), your equation does not hold.

Thanks. So, the following would therefore hold, right?$
p(A|B,C) = \frac{p(A|B)p(B,C|A)}{p(B,C)} $

This equation then becomes  $p(B)p(BC)=p(AB)$, so still if you assume this then what you are proposing is true. You can apply the Bayes’ theorem to check.


$$\frac{p(A \& B | C)}{p(A \& B)}.$$
Is it true that this is the same as the following?
$$\frac{p(A|C)p(B|A,C)}{p(A)p(B|C)} $$

No, but the following is:
$$ \frac{p(A \,\&\, B \mid C)}{p(A \,\&\, B)}=\frac{p(A\mid C)\,p(B\mid A,C)}{p(A)\,p(B\mid A)} $$

Thanks. So, the following would therefore hold, right?$
p(A|B,C) = \frac{p(A|B)p(B,C|A)}{p(B,C)} $

@JohnBlack No.
That would be: $$\dfrac{p(A)~p(B,C\mid A)}{p(B,C)}$$
